# Get Sending Text Message in Android before send

Tags: android, sms

I want to write some script that can filter Sending text message

**Explanation:**

***Example :if i write "ABC" in my text message and press send button ,then my script execute on this text before send and check if text has "ABC" then show me Message.***

basically i wants to get Send Message Text before sending Message .

Is it Possible ?
if anyone has some script then it will be help full.

Comment: use textwatcher in your edittext.

Comment: Actually i did not wants to make send message script, i wants to get send message Text from any application.

Comment: you think is it Possible?

Comment: check my simple answer...

Comment: Yeah i looks nice , but i wants to get text from default android text message application , do you think it will be Ok in That case ??

Comment: my answer fully depends on your question. you can easily track your sending message and change it if you want before sending. in default android text message application you also have to send message from your edittext and it will must a string. so everything is possible .

Comment: did you want test this condition on your own SMSManger or on very SMS that goes out?

Comment: yeah for my sms Module i can write code , but what about is i wants to take data from other application

Answer (score 0):

on Button click . First get the text of the edittext like:

```
String text = edittext1.getText().toString();
```

Then check the text is perfect or not: Like:

```
if(text.length() > 0 && text.equals("ABC"){ 
   //Send message
  }
else{
   //dont send or do what you want when text is not perfect
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Android SMSManager is responsible for sending messages.

```
SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(
                           destinationNo,
                           serviceCenterNo,
                           messageToSend,
                           sentIntent,
                           deliveryIntent);
```

Perform your operations on text before this call.